# What would you call people from Gaul?

Tags: word-request, nouns, demonyms

So we have Italians, people from Italy but British, people from Britain.
The Welsh from Wales etc.

Is there a rule or do you just have to learn them all?

What would you call people from Gaul? And the speaker in the podcast was calling them Gaulians but it didn't sound right (but Gaulish sounds worse doesn't it).

Source: Native speaker who was wondering this last night in bed.

Comment: There's no general rule, and lots of exceptions: [here's a list for countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectival_and_demonymic_forms_for_countries_and_nations). If you don't know or can't find out, you can add -ian in most cases, or just use the base form (without -ia or similar ending) as Gaul/Gauls, Slovene/Slovenes.

Comment: @StuartF - There's also lots of cases where the demonym is different from the adjective, e.g., Jan Janssen from Sweden _is a Swede_ (demonym) but _is Swedish_ (adjective).

Answer (score 6):

The (modern English) demonym for people from the area named by the Romans as Gallia (or [Gaul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaul)) is [*Gauls*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauls) in the plural (‘The Gauls were a Celtic tribe that lived in what is modernly called France’), or *Gaul* in the singular (‘The comic book character Asterix was supposed to have been a Gaul.’)

Comment: Yes! Britons were from Britain and Gauls were from Gaul.

Comment: Yes! _Asterix the Gaul_ is the title of the English edition of the first book of the series. _Astérix le gaulois_ in French. His name lost an acute accent for the 1969 English edition.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - In the French version, he was a [cigarette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauloises)?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin- No, those are _Gauloises_!

Comment: @KateBunting - ...which is given as the pl/f of "gaulois". :)

Comment: @KateBunting - yes, une gauloise was a female native of Gaul, giving rise to a brand name; Astérix was no more a cigarette (better not write 'fag', eh?) than Philip Morris or Winston. I do note that 'Alain Delon' is a cigarette brand in Cambodia.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - French does not capitalise nouns or adjectives of nationality, so une gauloise is a lady from Gaul, and une Gauloise is, as Groucho Marx probably didn't say, 'a smoke'.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - Yes, I know that, hence the exclamation mark!

Answer (score 2):

A native of Gaul was called a *Gaul* and the adjective to describe them was *Gallic*.

Google does turn up examples of 'Gaulian' being used for natives of Gaul; however, the majority of the results are for a fictitious alien species in the *Star Wars* universe, so while it might be an acceptable alternative it doesn't seem to be favoured.

Interestingly, the ancient region of Galatia was named for the Gallic people and its inhabitants were called Galatians.

Comment: Going with this as the answer because the disambiguation of Galatians is useful.